# magento show a slider in every page

Tags: php, jquery, magento-1.7

I am just a newbie to the [magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/). I wanted a [slider](http://beacon9.ca/labs/jquery-banner-rotator-script) in the homepage so I just downloaded the slider files. Then I made a file called `slide-banner.phtml` under `/app/design/frontend/themename/default/template/cms`. Then in that file my code was something like this

```
<script  src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('js/bannerRotator.js');?>"></script>
<script  src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js');?>"></script>
<script language="javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    bannerRotator('#bannerRotator', 500, 5000, true);
  });
</script>
<div id="bannerRotator">
  <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('homepageslider')->toHtml(); ?>
</div>
```

After that I just made a static block from admin dashboard under cms and named that as `homepageslider`. In that static block I just uploaded the images, after that my markup code was like this

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#"><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/15a.jpg"}}" alt="" /></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/11a.jpg"}}" alt="" /></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/12a.jpg"}}" alt="" /></a></li>
</ul>
```

After that in `admin cms>pages>home>content` I called the file as 
`{{block type="core/template" name="b-name" template="cms/slide-banner.phtml"}}`
Now here it is working fine to show the banner images with all the jQuery working. Now I want the same jQuery slider in `product page, checkout page, account page`. So can someone tell me how to do this.How to use that slider in each page? Any help and suggestions will be appreciable.

Comment: check out http://benfrain.com/magento-how-to-add-a-jquery-image-and-content-carousel/

Answer (score 0):

Either you can create a widget from the back-end and add you static block there and define the page you want it to display.

OR

You can go directly to the relevent .phtml files and add your code there.

Eg.  add in cart.phtml :

```
<script  src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('js/bannerRotator.js');?>"></script>
<script  src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js');?>"></script>
<script language="javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    bannerRotator('#bannerRotator', 500, 5000, true);
  });
</script>
<div id="bannerRotator">
  <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('homepageslider')->toHtml(); ?>
</div>
```

OR

You can add the static block in their `relevant .xml` files.